# MySQL query performance seems to scale linearly with number of parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a setup like such:

- using mysql 5.5
- a building has a set of measurement equipment
- measurements are stored in measurements -table
- there are multiple different types
- users can have access to either a whole building, or a set of equipment
- a few million measurements

The table creation looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `measurements` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`building_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`equipment_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`state` ENUM('normal','high','low','alarm','error') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normal',
`measurement_type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `building_id` (`building_id`),
INDEX `equipment_id` (`equipment_id`),
INDEX `state` (`state`),
INDEX `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
INDEX `measurement_type` (`measurement_type`),
INDEX `building_timestamp_type` (`building_id`, `timestamp`, `measurement_type`),
INDEX `building_type_state` (`building_id`, `measurement_type`, `state`),
INDEX `equipment_type_state` (`equipment_id`, `type`, `state`),
INDEX `equipment_type_state_stamp` (`equipment_id`, `measurement_type`, `state`, `timestamp`),
) COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now I need to query for the last 50 measurements of certain types that the user has access to. If the user has access to a whole building, the query runs very, very fast. However, if the user only has access to separate equipments, the query execution time seems to grow linearly with the number of equipment_ids. For example, I tested having only 2 equipment_ids in the IN query and the execution time was around 10ms. At 130 equipment_ids, it took 2.5s. The query I'm using looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `measurements`
WHERE
    `measurements`.`state` IN ('high','low','alarm')
    AND `measurements`.`equipment_id` IN (
        SELECT `equipment_users`.`equipment_id`
        FROM `equipment_users`
        WHERE `equipment_users`.`user_id` = 1
    )
    AND (`measurements`.`measurement_type` IN ('temperature','luminosity','humidity'))
ORDER BY `measurements`.`timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

The query seems to favor the `measurement_type` index which makes it take 15seconds, forcing it to use the `equipment_type_state_stamp` index drops that down to the listed numbers. Still, why does the execution time go up linearly with the number of ids, and is there something I could do to prevent that?

Comment: How many ids does a user commonly have access to? Is 130 a realistic number? Also: how many rows per `equipment_id` are there typically? Is it correct that it is theoretically possible to get the same equipment_id 50 times (if a user e.g. has only access to a single equipment, he will get its last 50 measurements), and is that that the intended result in such a situation?

Comment: The number of equipment_ids a user has access to varies greatly, from just a few to several hunderds, 130 was just my middle-of-the-ground testing number. And yes, if the user only has access to a single equipment, then he'd get only measurements from that one equipment.

Comment: It will depend a lot on your actual data which way will be the fastest, that is why I asked for some numbers, and especially on how many rows the user typically has access to (without the limit). It is very different if you have 1.000.000 equipment ids with 10 measurements each and a user has access to 10-100 equipment ids, or if you have 100 equiments ids with 100.000 measurements each. Side question: Do you have in index on `(user_id, equipment_id)` and is it used when you force the index `equipment_type_state_stamp`?

Comment: Yeah makes sense. I checked and the current maximum number of equipment_ids a user has access to is 400, but there are only a few users with numbers over 100. Most are around 20-50. Equipment_ids there are maybe 100.000 in total. And yes, that index exists and is used. I also tested using `IN (1,2,3,....)` but that didn't seem to affect performance.

Comment: For your situation, I would have tried `equipment_type_state_stamp` as well. But you might profit from a covering index: Try `select equipment_id, state from ...` instead of `select *`. If it speeds up enough, you should add all other columns you use to the index, and/or use only the ones you actually need in your `select`. You may also try the index `(timestamp, equipment_id, measurement_type, state)` and an index `(equipment_id, user_id)` on the other table (again, test with `select equipment_id, state from`), it can be faster for some users (with more equipment), depending on your data.